# Execution of google perflkit failing due to syntax error in <packages>\gflags.py

Tags: python-3.x, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I was trying to use google's new opensource cloud performance bench marking tool perfkit. I was following the steps as mentioned in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/PerfKitBenchmarker for GCP. After successfully completing all the steps but last, I was executing the command: pkb.py --project= --benchmarks=iperf --machine_type=f1-micro
This command threw a syntax error from one of the dependent package "gflags.py"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PerfKitBenchmarker-0.11.1\pkb.py", line 19, in <module>
    from perfkitbenchmarker.pkb import Main
  File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\PerfKitBenchmarker-0.11.1\perfkitbenchmarker\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import gflags as flags  # NOQA
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gflags.py", line 1091
    except gflags_validators.Error, e:
                                  ^
```

OS: Windows7;
Python: 3.4.3;
Perfkitbenchmarker: v0.11.1

Comment: You need to use Python 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfkit/gflags does not support Python 3.x. You need to use Python 2.x.